# Get AD users out of mutliple Groups

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I need to export a list that shows all users member of three different groups.

Here is my first try:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$desktop = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "group1" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname
$officetd = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "group2" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname
$officepro = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "group3" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname
```

I have tried to filter out by piping the first variable like this :

```
$desktop | Where-Object {$_ -contains $officetd}
```

But it won't work.

Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't work"? What are you expecting to happen? (Update your question rather than responding with a comment.)

Comment: Flip your contains. Right now you are checking to see if a string contains an array. That is just silly.

Answer (score 1):

Almost .... try this:

```
$desktop | Where-Object {$_ -in $officetd -and $_ -in $officepro}
```

For this task you have a few slightly different options. Either you check if a single element is **in** a collection of elements, like the code above does it. Or you check if a collection of elements **contains** a single element, like the code below does it:

```
$desktop | Where-Object {$officetd -contains $_ -and $officepro -contains $_}
```

So it is important to chose the right "direction" of the comparison.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.